# There is a way to return an error inside catch without throw a new one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a custom error that I call inside try. And I want to return this error inside catch without throw a new one.

```
const callSomething = async () => {
  try {
    doSomething();
  } catch (error) {
    // This function receive the error with the additional properties, so we need the custom error object
    customErrorTreatment(error);
  }
};
```

This function is where the error is first call.

```
const doSomething = async () => {
 try {   
    // This function throw a custom error class with additional properties
    throwApiError({
      responseMessage: 'Some error occour',
      responseStatus: 500,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // If I return error, the function callSomething just receive the value without error.
    return error;

    // I can call throwApiError again, but feels ugly, that is the only way?
    return throwApiError({
      responseMessage: error.responseMessage
      responseStatus: error.status,
    });
  }
};
```

This is the custom error class and function

```
export const ApiError = class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor({ responseMessage, responseStatus, error }) {
    super(error);
    this.responseMessage = responseMessage;
    this.responseStatus = responseStatus;
  }
};
const throwApiError = ({ responseMessage, responseStatus, error }) => {
  throw new ApiError({ responseMessage, responseStatus});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `throwApiError()` again. Just `throw error` if you want the promise to stay rejected - that's how promises work.

Or get rid of your catch() handler entirely so the error just propagates naturally back up to a higher level without your intervention. You don't appear to be doing anything in the catch handler so perhaps you can just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

In short No, because to generate an error you need to `throw`, and your method is a common method for error handling. but  there is another way to manage errors like this:

```
const callSomething = async () => {
  let { result, error } = resdoSomething();
  if (error) {
    return throwApiError({
      responseMessage: error.responseMessage
      responseStatus: error.status,
    });
  }
  console.log(result)
  // do somethings
};
```

and

```
const doSomething = async () => {
 try {   
   let result = myfunction()
   return {result: result , error : null}
  } catch (error) {
    return {result : null, error: error};
  }
};
```

In this way you can reduce the number of try/catch

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We are avoiding this pattern because it doesn't generate status code.